Task not waited in Console application
Based on this question, I am trying to have a console app run two tasks.
The problem is that the console app exits before the tasks finish running and I don't know how could I wait for their completion.
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Action<string> action = async (string s) =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{s} action executing");
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }
    };
    var secondTask = Task.Run(() => action("second"));

    var firstTask = Task.Run(() => action("first"));

    Task.WhenAll(firstTask, secondTask).Wait();
}

What if instead of the actions I have actual async methods that I need to call? How do I wait for these to finish executing?

You should use Func<string,Task> instead of Action

@SomeBody because the Action won't return the Task, is it? That's brilliant! Please add this as an answer and I will mark it.

If you had actual async function you would write await MyFunction1(), await MyFunction2() If you want to runt them in parallel you would write await Task.WhenAll(MyFunction1(), MyFunction2())

Action<string> action = async (string s) creates an async void action(string s) delegate that can't be awaited. It's equivalent to writing:
static async void action(string s) =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{s} action executing");
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }
}

Either use Func<Task> or better yet, use a local function :
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    async Task action(string s) =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{s} action executing");
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }
    };
    var secondTask = Task.Run(() => action("second"));

    var firstTask = Task.Run(() => action("first"));

    await Task.WhenAll(firstTask, secondTask);
}

Using Func<string,Task> also works, but allocates a new delegate every time the method is called:
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Func<string,Task> action = async (string s) =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{s} action executing");
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }
    };
    var secondTask = Task.Run(() => action("second"));

    var firstTask = Task.Run(() => action("first"));

    await Task.WhenAll(firstTask, secondTask);
}

Update
As phuzi notes, Task.Run can be eliminated in this case. In this case Task.Run returns the inner task directly anyway.
var secondTask = action("second");

var firstTask = action("first");

await Task.WhenAll(firstTask, secondTask);

Task.Run can be useful if action contains significant blocking work before it starts performing asynchronous work, eg:
async Task action(string stock)
{
  var trade=RunSuperStockPredictionModel(stock);
  await client.PostTradeAsync(trade);
}

var secondTask = Task.Run(() => action("GOOG"));
var firstTask = Task.Run(() => action("MSFT"));

In this case though it's better to separate the blocking component into a separate method

Could you also do away with the Task.Run(() => ...) wrappers around the calls to action()?

@phuzi of course, in fact Task.Run itself returns the inner task directly. I assume action function is just a placeholder for a real time consuming operation though. Task.Run could be useful if action contained blocking code before any asynchronous operations

"Using Func<string,Task> also works, but": it throws a  "Parameter 1 is declared as type 'string' but should be 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'"

@Luuk (facepalm)  The comment is correct, the code is wrong. It should be Func<string,Task> action = async (string s)

@phuzi if the goal is to parallelize the two operations, then the Task.Run is needed. The Task.Run invokes the action delegate on the ThreadPool, so the two operations while start running right away, unless the ThreadPool is saturated. Without Task.Run the operations will be launched synchronously on the current thread, so their parallelization is not guarantied (it becomes dependant on their implementation, instead of depending on the ThreadPool availability, which is a safer bet in general).

@TheodorZoulias only if the operations have a synchronous component. If they're just async calls, they will run concurrently. In general there's no in general, it depends on what the code does. Using Task.Run(()=>client.GetAsJsonAsync()) is just wasteful. If you have to do significant work before that, yes you need Task.Run

What exactly is it wasted with the Task.Run? If you think that offloading invocations to the ThreadPool is wasteful, you should stop using the Parallel.ForEachAsync, because it is doing exactly that. When the intention is "parallelism", the implementation that communicates this intention is ThreadPool. If you don't want to use the ThreadPool, fine, but don't call it parallelism, call it asynchronous concurrency.
